# Pass data to viewController

Tags: arrays, swift, viewcontroller

I want to pass a dynamic data from one view controller to other. Normally I do it like this suppose I have

```
//FirstVC
let dataArr = ["2,5","5,1"]
//In SecondVC declared this var
var array: [String]()
//From VC one I pass it like this
let vc = SecondVC()
vc.array = dataArr
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

This is okay I am retrieving the array in my SecondVC. And the question is that what if these array are dynamic and multiple of them how can I pass multiple datas? For example

```
let dataArr = ["2,5","5,1"]
let dataArr = ["2","5"]
let dataArr = ["2,2","1,1"]
```

and so on any ideas how to pass them? Thank you beforehand

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic and multiple"? Does it change over time after presenting the second view controller? Or do you want to change it using the second view controller and send the result back to the first controller?

Comment: @LeoDabus I mean quantity of arrays is unknown

Comment: `dataArr: [[Int]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can store an array of Ints or strings, like this...

Strings

```
let dataArray = [["2", "5"], ["5", "1"]]
```

Ints

```
let dataArray = [[2, 5], [5, 1]]
```

Or You can create a struct called twoInts for example and store it as an array of type twoInts

The code would look like this

```
struct twoInts {
    var intOne: Int!
    var intTwo: Int?

    init(intOne: Int, intTwo: Int?) {
        self.intOne = intOne
        self.intTwo = intTwo
    }
 }
```

Then just store it as an array of twoInt

```
let dataArray = [twoInts(2, 5), twoInts(5, 1)]
```

Then access them individually

```
let firstNumber = dataArray[0].intOne // returns 2
let secondNumber = dataArray[0].intTwo! // return 5, intTwo is optional
```